# Why is Git adding commits to a different project's branch of the one i am working on?

Tags: git

Please look at the attached image [image: shot of git commit]
You will see that I am working in a directory called Trainingproject, I added a commit and for some reason it is on a branch of another project which is in a completely different directory. Why is this happening and how can i fix this?
The branch *follow-artist* is the branch of a different project in another directory, this project *Trainingproject* should not be going to that branch since it has its own repo.

Comment: `it is on a branch of another project which is in a completely different directory` What does that mean? How are you determining that?

Comment: Where is the root of your repository? Maybe it's a few directories up so both your projects are in the *same* repo by accident.

Comment: it's also possible that someone helpfully decided to set `$GIT_DIR`

Comment: Oh, also, you might want to run `git rev-parse --git-dir` and post the output (being the location of the `.git` directory)

Answer (score 2):

I don’t really know where you are taking from that it’s committing to another project, but a Git working directory has access to all the branches of a repository.

You can see the current branch using `git status` which will probably tell you that you are on the branch `follow-artists` right now. `follow-artists` is a branch of the repository that is located within `Trainingproject` though.

I suggest you to read through Git Book’s [branching chaper](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching) to understand what’s going on.

Comment: You beat me to it! The only thing I have left to contribute is that the `git branch` command is also handy for checking which branch you're on... but `git status` works too.

Comment: That branch is the branch of another project, this project should not be going to that branch since it has its own repo, sorry if my question is unclear i will edit it

Comment: @cdm89 Well, fact is though, that the project you are currently in has a branch with that name (it is probably not the same just because it is named the same). Also, branches usually don’t have their own repositories, but branches coexist within a single repository.

Comment: @poke But why does it have this branch when i never created the branch with that name for this project?

Answer (score 0):

With git, your working copy changes when you are on a different branch. Perhaps you want to `checkout` the right branch.

Answer (score 0):

***It is most definitely not a bug***. `follow-artists` is the branch name you are on. The `TrainingProjects` folder must be a subdirectory in the root of your Git repo. Your Git repo currently has the `follow-artists` branch checked out into the working copy.

You can see which branch you currently have checked out using the following command:

```
$ git branch
* follow-artists
  master
```

The asterisk shows which branch is currently checked-out into your working copy.

If you add the following to your `.bashrc` file, you'll be able to see the branch-name in your terminal prompt:

```bash
PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]'
PS1="$PS1"'\u@\h '
PS1="$PS1"'\[\e[0;33m\]\w'
PS1="$PS1"'$(__git_ps1 " \[\e[0m\](\[\e[0;36m\]%s\[\e[0m\])") '
PS1="$PS1"'\[\e[0;35m\]'
PS1="$PS1"'\[\e \D{%I:%M:%S %p}\[\e[0m\]\n$ '
```

which will look like this:

```
dinom829@machine ~/projects/TrainingProjects (follow-artists) 10:37:38 AM
$
```